# difference between props.fun and props.fun() in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `onClick` event handler when using functional components in reactjs.

I am calling it the following way;

```
onClick={ props.function }
```

rather than;

```
onClick={ props.function() }
```

I got an explanation that the below code won't work because it will be called immediately instead of passing it down. I didn't get that fully. Can anyone please explain?

```
onClick={ props.function() }
```

Comment: When you add `()` after function call, it will call it. But you want to call this function on click event, so you will have to pass the reference to it. This is done by using function name without parenthesis. Hope it explains your confusion

Comment: Just understand that functions are objects, and everything will make sense.

Comment: `onClick={props.function()}` will instruct your dom to fire `props.function()` every time it renders. Best practice is to nest your function within an arrow function like so: `onClick={() => props.function()}`

Comment: is using the arrow function and calling it like props.function the same?

Comment: Basically, yes. Arrow functions just handle the `.bind(this)` stuff for you. Useful if scope is applicable ie. when calling `this` from within the function.

Comment: ok. And once i got an error when i call the function like below:                                       onClick={ () => this.function().bind(this) }         why? What is the difference between this way and the right way; like                                                                    onClick={ () => this.function() }

Comment: `this.function().bind(this)` doesn't call function(). It creates a variable which binds `function` to `this`, and then since you are not assigning that variable to anything, it is thrown away. So that code sets the onClick handler to a function that does nothing.

Comment: FYI, the word `function` is a reserved word in javascript, so it's best never to use it as a variable or function name.

Comment: yeah..sure..thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, Objects are copied by reference. What this means is, when you do `var a = {}` or `function a() {}`, a memory location is assigned where value related to this variable will be stores.

The variable in turn will hold the memory location and not the actual value.

Not to invoke a function, you need to add parenthesis `()` after function name.

Since you want to call this function on click event, you will have to pass reference to handler, so that when event is triggered, your function is called.

Now, you might even face a scenario where you wish to pass parameters to such function for some processing.

In such scenario, you can do `functionName.bind(context, arguments)`

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea is that the event handler should have a reference to a function... when you use `function()` you pass what is returned from that function to the click handler ... which is `undefined` ... so later triggering click will result in calling `undefined` and will never work

So lets say we have

```
handleClick(){
 console.log("clicked")
}
```

if we used

```
onClick={ handleClick() }
```

when you check the console you will find "clicked" is logged after the component render, so its called immediately.

But it will not be called later `onClick` because the `onClick` event is now not handled by a function reference its handled by whatever is returned by that function call which is `undefined` now

To understand this more lets consider the following example

```
handleClickWithFunction(){
   return function(){
     console.log("clicked");
   }
}
```

now if you used

```
onClick={ handleClickWithFunction() }
```

It should work because as soon as the component render the `handleClickWithFunction` is executed and return another function that will `console.log("clicked")` so now the event is handled by a reference to the function that was returned by `handleClickWithFunction`